# Getting tag of UILabel on click

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am dynamically creating UILabels and then saving their tag in an NSMutableArray. I then have a method that detects taps (clicks) on these UILabels. Basically when a UILabel that has been dynamically generated is clicked I want to have it deleted without deleting other labels. However, in future I may want to do more then just delete. But at the moment I feel like I am stuck at a dead end trying to find a way to do this. Any ideas?

Heres my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
// set corner radius
coverview.hidden=YES;
labeltextfield.hidden=YES;
textcreate.hidden=YES;


labeltags = [NSMutableArray  array];
labeltext = [NSMutableArray array];

}

-(IBAction)removeboard
{
[labeltextfield resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)showtextcreator {
// Create bg cover
coverview.hidden=NO;
labeltextfield.hidden=NO;
textcreate.hidden=NO;

//Make sure creating screen is always on top
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:coverview];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:labeltextfield];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:textcreate];

}

-(void)createtext {    
NSInteger obj = [labeltags count] +1 ;
[labeltags addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0]];

int posx = arc4random() % 300 ;
int posy = arc4random() % 400 ;
int frame = arc4random() % 400 ;

NSString *txt = labeltextfield.text;
//  NSString *framename = (@"frame%i",frame);

[labeltext addObject:txt];

[labeltags addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0]];

CGRect labelframe = CGRectMake( posx, posy, 100, 30);
 label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: labelframe];
[label setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", txt]];
[label setTextColor: [UIColor orangeColor]];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.tag=obj;
[self.view addSubview: label];

label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                    initWithTarget:self
                                    action:@selector(labelDragged:)];
[label addGestureRecognizer:gesture];

UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction)];

[label addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];



coverview.hidden=YES;
labeltextfield.hidden=YES;
textcreate.hidden=YES;


}

- (void)labelDragged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
label = (UILabel *)gesture.view;
CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:label];

// move label
label.center = CGPointMake(label.center.x + translation.x,
                           label.center.y + translation.y);

// reset translation
[gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:label];
}


- (void)tapAction {
    UILabel *labelnew = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
    NSLog(@"Text is %@",labelnew.text);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)];
[label addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

- (void)tapAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture {
    UILabel *labelTapped = (UILabel *)tapGesture.view;
   //delete it using removeFromSuperView or do whatever you need with tapped label

}
```

Details:

1.Modify your `-(void)createtext` method.

2: Add a parameter to the target for `UITapGestureRecognizer`

3.Receive the sender gesture in `- (void)tapAction:`

4.Get the tapped  `UILabel`.

Thats it.

Comment: Amazing! I used removeFromSuperView and it worked great. Thank you very much.